# Is there a possibility to change compiler engine depending on presence of a package

Tags: compiling, latexmk, arara

I'm used to use both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` engine to compile my documents, `xelatex` in case of `.tex` files containing `polyglossia` package and `pdflatex` for the others

My question is there a method ( with latexmk or arara or any other program ) to compile my documents in a conditional manner

```
if tex file contain "polyglossia" then 
  use xelatex 
else 
  use pdflatex
fi
```

NB I have windows OS on my pc.

Comment: why not just put an arara or editor comment at the top to say to use xetex?

Comment: I need same comment (method) for all my files, I do not want to change it from file to another

Comment: it is in general very unreliable just to look for `polyglossia` it might be commented out or in `\ifxetex \usepackage{polyglossia}\else \usepackage{babel}\fi` etc so an explicit comment at the top is always going to be more reliable.

Comment: In theory arara 4.0 has this cool new feature where you can check if a file contains a specific string, meaning you questions would be answered with `% arara: xelatex if found('tex', 'polyglossia')
% arara: pdflatex if !found('tex', 'polyglossia')`, however in reality this does not work, as the comment to instruct arara makes sure that "polyglossia"  will be within the file, so it will always use xelatex ...

Comment: @samcarter And it would be subject to the problems David mentioned. Or `polyglossia` might be loaded via another package or ....

Comment: Why do all your documents have to have the same comment? Changing it is one word in your source. What, really, could be easier than that?

Comment: If *all* you want is a literal check for 'polyglossia', that's easy enough. On any Unix-ish system, presumably on Windows, though it never does to count on these things. So you can write a script to check and then trigger the relevant binary. But that would be an extremely unreliable method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm on windows too. My editor, Winedt, has macro capabilities and it would be easy to write a macro to start the compilation which does want you ask for. 
It is also not every difficult to devise other methods with other scripts languages with similar effects.

But imho you would learn very fast to hate such automation.

It is so very easy to imagine documents where your test doesn't do what you want. Starting with documents which can be compiled with both engines, documents which should use xetex but use babel instead of polyglossia, documents where the relevant packages are buried in a preamble.tex, document where behind \end{document} are comments and rests of other documents, documents where some of the packages are commented or inside `\if`-clauses, documents without fontspec or polyglossia but which should be compiled with xetex as they use pstricks, ...

It is also easy to imagine situations where you don't want an automation, e.g. if you want to compare the output of a xelatex compilation with a lualatex or pdflatex or latex + dvipdfmx compilation.

It would imho cost you much more time to handle all this situations than it would cost you to add a comment about the compilation at the top. Also you as a human are much better in deciding about the correct compilation method than a script.

---

### EDIT: How to achieve this in WinEdt?

As simple as drinking a glass of water... (almost)

Create a file named `XeORPdf.edt` in the WinEdt Appdata directory `%b\Exec\TeX` with the following contents:

```
// xelatex or pdflatex?

PushTagsandRegisters;

  GetPreamble("\begin{document}",9);
  FindInString("%!9","<@{ }\\usepackage@{\[**\]}\{@^{\}|%%|polyglossia}polyglossia{,| |\}}",7,8,11);
  IfNum(%!7,%!8,"<",!"Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\XeLaTeX.edt');",!"Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFLaTeX.edt');");

PopTagsandRegisters;

End;
```

Then, in your local `MainMenu.ini` (open it through the options interface), add the following lines

```
  ITEM="XeORPdf"
    CAPTION="XeLaTeX or PDFLaTeX"
    IMAGE="Question"
    SAVE_INPUT=1
    MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\XeORPdf.edt');"
    REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
  ITEM="-"
```

somewhere, let's say after the lines

```
MENU="TeX_Menu"
  CAPTION="Te&X"
  CONFIG_FILTER="Default;MiKTeX;TeX Live"
```

to have the new command on top of the "TeX" menu:

[image]

If you want to have it in the toolbar, too, simply add the line

```
  BUTTON="XeORPdf"
```

somewhere in your local `Toolbar.ini`.

Load the scripts with the "load script" icon in the options interface, or my using `Options->maintenance->rebuild all`.

Now if your `.tex` file contains a non-commented line like

```
\usepackage[...]{...,polyglossia,...}
```

xelatex is executed, otherwise pdflatex is.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike Fischer for  your remarks, but most time I'm facing this situation files with polyglossia which need to be compiled with `xelatex` and others files mostly with `fontenc` compiled with `pdflatex`.  For `lualatex` and `pstricks` never use them

Comment: "most time" is not enough.

Comment: delete the edit if you don't like it :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller: The edit is fine. And while I don't think that it is really useful I'm quite willing to let people try out for themselves.

Comment: I followed all the steps but `"XeLaTeX or PDFLaTeX"` did not appear in `TeX`  menu.

Comment: Did you load the MainMenu.ini script? (Options menu -> options interface and then click on the left icon "load script") when the MainMenu.ini has the focus. Or options ->maintenance->rebuild all.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of `arara` is that you can customise the build process on a per-document basis rather than relying on a tool that has to try to work out the build sequence. It seems like overkill to use a Java application to perform something that could easily be done in a script, but if you really want to use `arara` and the problem cases don't apply in your document, then here's one way to do achieve it.

Following on from @samcarter's comment, `arara` v4.0 allows conditions, but you need to be quite particular about the pattern¹. For example, rather that checking for any instance of `polyglossia`, check specifically for `\usepackage{polyglossia}` occurring at the start of a line:

```
% arara: xelatex if found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
% arara: pdflatex unless found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

This runs `xelatex`, whereas

```
% arara: xelatex if found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
% arara: pdflatex unless found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

runs `pdflatex` and so will

```
% arara: xelatex if found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
% arara: pdflatex unless found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

(since there's a space character between the start of the line and `\usepackage{polyglossia}`).

There are some situations where this will go wrong, as already mentioned in Ulrike's answer. For example:

```
% arara: xelatex if found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
% arara: pdflatex unless found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

or

```
% arara: xelatex if found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
% arara: pdflatex unless found("tex", "\\R\\\\usepackage\\{polyglossia\\}")
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifusepoly
\usepolyfalse

\ifusepoly
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\else
\usepackage{babel}
\fi

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

---

¹See the [Pattern class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a list of available regular expression constructs. It's a bit awkward as backslashes need escaping when supplying the expression as a string, so `\R` indicates a line break but this needs to be written as `\\R` to avoid being interpreted as a control character.

Answer (score 2):

In case `polyglossia` may be hidden in some other packages or subfiles or another package needs xelatex, maybe you could use an explicit error message to detect if xelatex is needed.

The following example requires `arara 4.0` and an additional run if there is not yet a `.log` file.

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {interaction: nonstopmode} if !exists('log') 
% arara: pdflatex: {interaction: nonstopmode} if exists('log') && !found('log', 'cannot-use-pdftex') 
% arara: xelatex: {interaction: nonstopmode} if exists('log') && found('log', 'cannot-use-pdftex') 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

*But make sure that your images or sections are not coincidentally called `cannot-use-pdftex` :)*

---

This technique can also be used for documents, which do not need to be compiled with xelatex, but for which this is the "intended" compilation chain. For example the `metropolis` beamer theme has a fallback for the compilation with pdflatex, but will tell you:

> You need to compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to use the Fira fonts

Comment: Interesting solution...how can I test it with version 4 of arara ?  Wait until version is released on tl?

Comment: @SalimBou The source code and `.jar` files are available from https://github.com/cereda/arara

Answer (score 1):

Example using `ifxetex` and `ifluatex` that should work with any compiler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
  \def\xxx{using \texttt{pdflatex}}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \def\xxx{using \texttt{xetex}}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \def\xxx{using \texttt{luatex}}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi

\begin{document}
Test \xxx
\end{document}
```