# Is there a way to make latexmk automatically switch between pdflatex and xelatex?

Tags: compiling, automation, latexmk

Assume I have some projects to be compiled with `pdflatex`, some with `xelatex`. For now I'm just passing an appropriate key to `latexmk` command in console, e.g.

```
latexmk -pdf ToBeCompiledWithPdflatex.tex
```

or

```
latexmk -xelatex ToBeCompiledWithXelatex.tex
```

because I find it counterproductive to change settings in TeXstudio or create `.latexmkrc` config file every time I need to switch between the projects. Is there a way to make latexmk automatically switch between `pdflatex` and `xelatex`?

I tried to find this option, unsuccessfully. I'd think this is rather an obvious thing to implement as there are many signs in the document which `latexmk` can utilize to determine what compiler to use without user's intervention. For instance, magic commands such as `% !TeX program = xelatex`, or `\usepackage{polyglossia}` in preamble would unambiguously signify that xelatex should be used. Am I missing something here?

Comment: you could call latexmk via arara and use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375701/is-there-a-possibility-to-change-compiler-engine-depending-on-presence-of-a-pack/376280#376280

Comment: @samcarter This sounds interesting, I've never used `arara` before. Though I'd rather stick with `latexmk` only as some of my collaborators use vscode+LaTeX Workshop extension for writing, and `latexmk` is the default way of compiling there.

Comment: How about simply `% !TeX program = latexmk -xelatex`?

Comment: @samcarter Now I feel stupid:) Nice suggestion, and it indeed works, at least in those editors which have support for magic commands. But still, it would be nice to have `latexmk` somehow do the recognition. In the meantime I'd recognize your comment as an answer; if you also feel like it, please post one:)

Comment: What is the criterion for making the decision?

Comment: `Latexmk` author here: I agree it would be useful for `latexmk` to recognize the `% !TeX program = ...` metacommands. But it doesn't do so at present.  I'll take this as a feature request, which has in fact been on my list of enhancements to be made.